# How to bubble chart aligned bottom and stick to each other

Tags: charts, d3.js, data-visualization

I would like to ask if there is a way to achieve the layout and arrangement of the circles on the image.
I would like create a chart of series of circles that are link together and all aligned in the bottom.

[image]

Comment: That imagen is not a chart?

Comment: i know but it's what i wast told to do ... hmmmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between two circles with radii r1 and r2 is:

[image: enter link description here]

You can use this to position your circles on the x-axis. For an example see: http://bl.ocks.org/7a9d6c4725367aaed5db .

Comment: your a genius Jan ... Thanks